# Trek bike needs identification

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, trek

I have a bike that I want to sell but I have forgotten and lost all the info I had about it. It's a Trek road bike with 105's and some mods, like the head tube. It looks to me like the it was powder coated, or is that original? Anything you can tell me would be helpful. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it looks a lot like my red Trek 330 from the early 1980's. But it's hard to know and hard to see why that matters.

Comment: "t's a trek road bike with 105's and some mods, like the head tube." - I think you mean that it's been converted to flat bar shifters. It's hard to modify the head tube itself.

Comment: @WeiwenNg  OP probably meaning the stem!

Comment: Is the serial number painted over? If you can still read it, the vintage trek website has info to determine model and year from the serial number. The number is likely stamped under the bottom bracket.

Comment: The downtube shifters makes it from maybe 1978 to 1986.

Comment: On the bottom bracket shell, down tube or seat tube will be a serial number most likely beginning with "T." It'll be much easier to find this model if you provide that information as the number has date codes and other clues as to where and when it was manufactured.  Include where exactly you found this number.

Answer (score 2):

The steel cast lugs on the frame were introduced to [Trek bikes in 1985](http://www.vintage-trek.com/Trek_timeline.htm).
Trek road bikes fell into three categories - touring, sport, racing - with wheel base, frame angles, and components appropriate to the category.

The tight seat tube to rear wheel clearance indicates a short wheel base racing bike.
The last year for a steel frame with a short wheel base is 1989 on the Trek 400, and 660.

For a steel frame with cast lugs between 1985 and 1989 I have found two racing bikes that came with Shimano 105 components.
- 1987 560 This model year head badge matches your frame
- 1988 560 Trek changed the head badge this year

So, it's possible that your bike is a 1987 560 with a swapped out handlebar and stem. Or, it the frame could be one of the other short wheelbase Trek road bike frames in 1987 with the handlebar, stem, and 105 components added.

Look at the [catalog for 1987](http://www.vintage-trek.com/Trek-Fisher-Klein-Lemond/1987trek.pdf) and compare the parts on your bike with the parts on the bike in the catalog. If you get a solid match then you have a 560.

Also, as Jeff and Andrew indicate in the comments to the original post your serial number may provide you with information about your frame via the [Serial Number Decoding Project.](http://www.vintage-trek.com/SerialNumbers.htm#SerialNumberProject)

Information derived from [vintage-trek.com](http://www.vintage-trek.com/trek-fisher-klein-lemond.htm)

Comment: The 105 components that are visible in the images are newer than 1987. I would operate under the assumption that none of the components are original to the bike.

Comment: @Andrew Makes sense to me. That would put the frame between 1985 and 1987 based on the lugs and the head tube badge.

Comment: Thank you @DavidD and @Andrew! This is so helpful,. And you're knowledge is incredible. So impressed.